# How to persist some fields in Generic class in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class as follows. What I need is, I need to use generics, and by using it I need to pass some classes that extend the SomeInfo class and persist a common field inside the SubClass table and when returning data I can populate `T` parameter and send it easily. But I can't extend SomeInfo class directly because it contains fields that I don't need to be created in the SubClass table and even I don't need to use the `Inheritance Single Table solution`. I have tried using `@AttributeOverride` but it threw an error and I used `@Type` annotation and the error was gone, but the field `info_name` isn't created.

```
@Entity
public class SubClass<T extends SomeInfo> extends ParentClass {

    @Type(type = "com.package.SomeInfo")
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "info_name", nullable = false))
    })
    private T info;
}

@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class SomeInfo extends ParentClass {

    // some fields
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I need? Thanks in advance.